# Fortnite not working after update for Season 5

Tags: fortnite-battle-royale

I have been playing Fortnite since Season 3, but never had any error related to the permissions to access game files. However, after the Season 5 update, I have been having issues in launching the game. Whenever I launch the game, the following error message appears:

[image: Error Message]

I am not a computer specialist, so I can't seem to understand the type of error or how to solve it. If anyone knows the solution, please help. Thanks for the attention.

Comment: Have you tried running the program as admin? (right click on it-> run as admin).

Answer (score 2):

3 methods I have used to solve this problem are

- Run as admin (right click -> run as admin)
- Restart your pc as occasionally files get locked by other processes and restarting can fix this.
- Reinstall the program. Occasionally the update gets messed up for a variety of reasons, and the only way to fix is reinstalling the app or running a repair tool if they have one.